# R handle vector values in addition to scalar values with rounding function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
round2 <- function(x, y) {
  if(is.na(x)) { return ('') }
  return(paste0(round(100 * x, 0), '% ', round(100 * y, 0), '%')) 
}

mydf <- data.frame(a = c(NA, .323, .555), b = c(NA, .232, .541))
mydf %>% dplyr::mutate(c = round2(a, b))
```

The main part of the function `paste0(round(...))` works just fine, however the `if(is.na(x)) { return ('') }` does not properly handle that x and y are vectors. As a result, the entire column `c` in `mydf` is an empty string. How can we update this so only the first row in `mydf` returns an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if/else` are not vectorized - expect a single `TRUE/FALSE` it can work if we use `rowwise` as grouping

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   rowwise %>%
   dplyr::mutate(c = round2(a, b)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
       a      b c        
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
1 NA     NA     ""       
2  0.323  0.232 "32% 23%"
3  0.555  0.541 "56% 54%"
```

as grouping or `Vectorize` the function

```
mydf %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(c = Vectorize(round2)(a, b))
```

---

If we want to create a vectorized function, make use of `ifelse/case_when` etc which are already vectorized

```
round2new <- function(x, y) {
    case_when(is.na(x) ~ "", 
   TRUE ~ paste0(round(100 * x, 0), '% ', round(100 * y, 0), '%'))
}
mydf %>%
   dplyr::mutate(c = round2new(a, b))
      a     b       c
1    NA    NA        
2 0.323 0.232 32% 23%
3 0.555 0.541 56% 54%
```

NOTE: Calling `Vectorize` or using `rowwise` grouping is iterating over each row and will be slower than making use of vectorized functions (`ifelse/case_when/if_else`) while constructing the function

Comment: is it possible to update round2 to handle vector parameters? this seems like a cleaner option than using Vectorize every time we call the function.

Comment: @Canovice thank you for the comment.  I updated with `case_when`

Answer (score 0):

the if () function if you pass a vector, it will only take the first value of vector..
also a warning will be displayed on console..

better you pass the vector in function call and use the
for call up to length of vector and check each x[j] j=1:length(x)

or you can use

> vec
> [1]  2  3 NA
> sum(is.na(vec))
> [1] 1

something like this in your logic building..